# query for search results with 'like'

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a good query string to get better search results.

at the moment I use the operator `like`

```
select title from table where lower(column) like '%data%'
```

but the results are not accurate enough.

My "search engine" is looking for events, news and webcontent on my website, so I want to get results with `'data'` as a word like `'Big-Data'`, `'Big Data.'`, `'All Data'`, but no results like `'maxdata'`, `'bigdata'`, `'datapool'`.  Can I use `REGEXP_LIKE`?

Comment: What is it that you do want to find?

Comment: Can you define your criteria of 'better search results'?

Comment: my "search machine" is looking for events, news and webcontent on my website, so I want to get results with 'data' as a word like 'Big-Data', 'Big Data.', 'All Data', but no results like 'maxdata', 'bigdata', 'datapool' ...

Comment: @Pit I updated your question with the details you provided in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select title 
from table 
where regexp_like(column, '(\W|^)data(\W|$)', 'i')
```